# AJAX sending and receiving different data type

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I made a basic AJAX function calling a php file. The response is a HTML to be inserted in a "content box" of my main page

```
function LoadAjax_alert_display_one(){
    id_alert = <?php echo $id_alerte; ?>;
    $('.preloader').show();
    $.ajax({
        mimeType: 'text/html; charset=utf-8', // ! Need set mimeType only when run from local file
        url: 'ajax/alert_display_one.php',
        data: "id_alerte="+id_alert,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#ajax-content').html(data);
            $('.preloader').hide();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        dataType: "html",
        async: false
    });
}
```

That's working fine. The called file 'alerts_create.php' is also runinng a php to get data from the database and displays it using a while loop

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='LoadAjax_alert_display_one();'>" . $nom_alerte . "</a></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $country . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";  }
```

My issue is that I cannot properly pass the link I create in the while loop. The $nom_alerte always takes the value of the last iteration of the loop. So my AJAX take this as link value;
any ideas how I can do that?

To clrify my title: my issue is to send a php variable to the called file ('alerts_create.php') and to retrieve an HTML result.

SOLUTION: just had to pass the php variable as the AJAX function parameter:

```
function LoadAjax_alert_display_one(id_alerte){
        $('.preloader').show();
    $.ajax({
        mimeType: 'text/html; charset=utf-8', // ! Need set mimeType only when run from local file
        url: 'ajax/alert_display_one.php',
        data: "id_alerte="+id_alerte,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#ajax-content').html(data);
            $('.preloader').hide();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        dataType: "html",
        async: false
    });
}
```

Comment: Create array in loop then pass into json format and decode it into ajax success function

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use .load() from jquery (since you are already using jquery)?

Comment: @AghaUmairAhmed: thanks for your answer; I am clearly not good enough to implement it. Would you be so kind to give me an example.

Comment: @Markai: no specific reason; I have to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = 'abc=0';
$.post(
  'yoururl.php',
  data
).success(function(resp){
   var json = $.parseJSON(resp);
   console.log(json);
});
```

and in php file use like this

```
while( $stmt->fetch() ) {
   $data[] = array(
     'link' => 'your link'
   );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I will try but I am still a bit lost. anyways; thanks again